# Gatsby client-side routes with multiple params

Tags: reactjs, react-router, gatsby

Users can have their own profile pages much like Twitter etc and is accessible via http://example.com/username. Because there are thousands of users I'm handling this dynamically and have created a client side route for this in my `onCreatePage`:

```
  if (page.path.match(/^\/user\/$/)) {
    createPage({
      ...page,
      matchPath: '/:identifier'
    })
  }
```

And it works as expected.

But users can also have "sub pages" that are also dynamic and should be client only, i.e. http://example.com/username/somepage. `somepage` is just a placeholder here but it referneces an `asset` ID which again there are potentially thousands of. So I would expect something like this to work:

```
  if (page.path.match(/^\/asset\/$/)) {
    createPage({
      ...page,
      matchPath: '/:identifier/:slug'
    })
  }
```

But it doesn't. It routes to the 404 page. I've also tried `/:identifier/*`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial slug to create the page (`createPage`) is handled by Gatsby in order to create the matching pages so I think leaving the code just like this should work:

```
  if (page.path.match(/^\/user\/$/)) {
    createPage({
      ...page,
      matchPath: '/:identifier/*'
    })
  }
```

The rest of URL parameters, can be handled by the router, with something like:

```
 <Router>
        <User path="/user/:identifier" />
        <UserAsset path="/user/:identifier/:asset" />
 </Router>
```

Comment: You led me on the right path. I could only get the desired behavior by changing my matchPath to `matchPath: '/:identifier/*'` and within my router index I could remove the `/user/` bit to get what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: I was editing the answer to add the asterisk to match all pages under `identifier` when you commented on it xD. I'm glad it helped you. Happy coding!